# Queuing observable requests

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a service which, after some validation, makes a call to my backend server

```
get(systems?: string[], options?: {}): Observable<System[]> {
    if (
        // cache check
    ) {
        // validate options
        return this.api.get('/systems', options)
            .map(response => {
                // proccess results, store to cache
            });
    } else {
        return Observable.of(this.systems);
    }
}
```

This request is called when the service is initialized, to get basic data (passing the options `{basic: true}`. On one of my pages, the same service is called on component initialization, without the basic option. However, when the site is loaded to that page, of course both HTTP requests fire, as neither has returned and populated the cache.

I can't seem to figure out how to best avoid this situation. In an ideal solution, the requests would queue, and I would use the cache logic to determine if another HTTP request was necessary or I could return cached data. However, that logic doesn't seem to fit the observable/observer pattern. I'd love some advice on how to address this.

Comment: You can add a cache service to centralize this kind of request, get it from cacheService let itself handle quequeing  instead of direct http call everytime.

Comment: In my sudo code above, where I mention caching, it's doing that check. But even if I sent it to a different service first, both calls would get there before any data is in the cache and make an HTTP request. I'd still need to somehow queue the requests. Can you explain how you think they'd avoid simultaneity?

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid **race conditions**, you need to cache Observables instead of caching values directly.

The issue with caching values directly is that you could have multiple calls made to your service back-to-back, and your service will check the cache for values that will not exist until your request completes (this creates the race condition -- where your request is racing against the logic that checks the cache). Your service will end up making multiple requests and overriding the cache of the same value multiple times.

By caching Observables, you place them in a cache immediately after they are created, and you return that Observable when any subscriber needs it (regardless of whether or not that Observable has resolved to a value), so you won't have multiple requests being made.

To make things easier, we can cache [`ReplaySubject`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/replaysubject.md) objects, which will retain the last value that was called using `next` and returns that value automatically when new subscribers `subscribe`. This is essentially a Subject that caches previous values and returns them to new subscribers.

See this simple example, where `cache` is an object representing a cache of `ReplaySubject`s:

```js
let cache = {};

getCached('key1').subscribe(val => console.log("Sub1: ", val)); // first subscriber
getCached('key1').subscribe(val => console.log("Sub2: ", val)); // second subscriber immediately after first

function getCached(key) {

  if(cache[key]) return cache[key]; // does cached Observable exist? If so, return it right away
  
  console.log("Not cached. Fetching new value.");
  
  cache[key] = new Rx.ReplaySubject(1); // set cache equal to new ReplaySubject
  
  setTimeout(() => cache[key].next(500), 1000); // fetch new value and alert our ReplaySubject subscribers
  
  return cache[key]; // return ReplaySubject immediately
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-rc.4/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>
```

The key thing to note about the example above is that `getCached('key1')` is called back-to-back before the cached value has had the chance to call `next` (which is delayed by 500 milliseconds) and the `ReplaySubject` is cached only **once** (notice the `console.log` only prints once, the first time that it sets the cache).

---

**Caching Options and Systems**

Because you need a new cache entry for every combination of `systems` and `options`, you can set your key equal to the string representation of `systems` + `options` by using `JSON.stringify` on `options`:

```js
let cache = {};

getCached('key1', {basic: true}).subscribe(val => console.log("Sub1: ", val)); // first subscriber
getCached('key1', {basic: true}).subscribe(val => console.log("Sub2: ", val)); // second subscriber immediately after first

getCached('key1', {basic: false}).subscribe(val => console.log("Sub3: ", val));

function getCached(systems, options) {

  const key = systems + JSON.stringify(options);
  
  console.log("key is: ", key);

  if(cache[key]) return cache[key]; // does cached Observable exist? If so, return it right away
  
  console.log("Not cached. Fetching new value.");
  
  cache[key] = new Rx.ReplaySubject(1); // set cache equal to new ReplaySubject
  
  setTimeout(() => cache[key].next(500), 1000); // fetch new value and alert our ReplaySubject subscribers
  
  return cache[key]; // return ReplaySubject immediately
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-rc.4/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>
```

Notice that the cache is updated only when a new combination of `systems` and `options` is used. In the example above, the unique keys are the following strings:

- `'key1{"basic":true}'`
- `'key1{"basic":false}'`

Comment: Thanks! I thought about caching the the observable itself, but I couldn't think of how I'd do it when different calls are being made; how do I generate a key when I don't know what parameters are going to come in?

Comment: If they `key` parameter is missing, you can have a default key, so something like `function getCached(key = 'default') {...}`, and you set `cache['default'] = defaultReplaySubject` when your service is instantiated. If a `key` is passed to `getCached`, then that key will be dynamically added to your cache as we are using bracket notation on the cache to add new keys.

Comment: In the example, the key is `'key1'`, but we could have made this anything else such as `'randomKey'`

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. As you can see in my service, the method takes 2 parameters, meaning depending on the parameter values, the observable can be different, unless I'm not understanding you correctly, which means I need to cache each one? But how do I cache them when they may be different? Or are you saying I need the key in the call?

Comment: Would you mind editing your question to include some different values of parameter1 and parameter2 and the expected cache value for that call? That will help me see what you mean.

Comment: Well, they're typed. `systems` is a string array, `options` is an object, and the return is an object. You want specific examples of what they could be? Does it matter? Any value you make up should be sufficient for example purposes, no? I don't mean to sound snippy, but I'm just confused why specific values should matter?

Comment: What I'm confused about is: what combination of `systems` and `options` will constitute a new entry in the cache? When I read your question, my interpretation was that calling the function with `{basic: true}` and calling it without `{basic: true}` should return the same entry -- is that correct? Or should it be that calling the function with different values for `options` creates a new entry in the cache?

Comment: Different values of options and systems yields different responses from the API.

Comment: Ah, I got you. See my updated response for caching unique combinations of `systems` and `options`

Comment: Thank you for helping with the cache explanation. I need to look more into Replays, but it makes sense! I'll test it out in the morning.